# when request a js file ,why need the cookie information(sessionid)

Tags: javascript, cookies

when request a js file ,why browers will add a param sessionid in http head cookie

below is the example

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset  GB2312,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language zh-cn,zh;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=A87429B9EB1AB5E8FFEEF62B2149ED48
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the file being js or otherwise.

Cookies apply to all resources that match their path.

The server may or may not care about the session data when it generates it's response.

Keeping static resources on a different host to which the cookies are not sent is one technique used to boost performance when fetching them. (There are other performance optimisations that can be applied at the same time, such as the use of a CDN to provide geographically local resources).

Comment: oh i understand a little,the cookie is to identify who request the js file>?? is that right

Comment: It *could* be used for that purpose but probably isn't. Most likely the server ignores it for JS files.

Comment: ignore it?why?the sessionid is useless?

Comment: The cookie, as I said, it sent with every request to the server. There needs to be explicit code on the server to do anything with it. There is rarely any reason to pay attention to it for js files so that code rarely exists. Since there is no code paying attention to it, it is ignored. In that context, the cookie is useless. It is just sent because the JS file is on the same server as resources which do care about the cookie.

Comment: you mean we can get sessionid in js code and use it ,in this case ,it is useful only

Comment: I didn't say that. You could get the session id using JS, but only by reading it from the browser environment … but that would be the cookie for the HTML document not the JS file. Since a session ID has no purpose but to have data associated with it *on the server*, getting it client side would be worthless.

Comment: then,how do we use sessionid in server..when client request a js file,server  handle the request??

Comment: Given it is a JSESSIONID, I would assume "with server side Java".

Comment: now  i have no idea to do it with server side...how to deal  with it with server side?

Comment: Why is there a JSESSIONID cookie being set by your site if you don't know how to use sessions?

Comment: sessionid is set when login and send by browser,i did not set it

Comment: i see a website,its cookie:BAIDUID=A735BEEF8BABA97A0B924992AA01DE53:FG=1; MCITY=-%3A,the name and value both can be setted..i search it to find how to set it ..thanks a lot...